# Database access abstraction classes

Tags: php, database, model, database-abstraction

Currently, I have a database access class named `DB`, which uses `PDO`. I Then have a handful of sub-classes for accessing each table:

- `Users`
- `Images`
- `Galleries`
- `Text`
- `Videos`

This was nice when I first started my project, but now I'm not sure if it's that great, as I have a method for each database query that I use within each of these classes. For example:

```
Images::insertNew($filename)
Images::getTotalInGallery($galleryId)
Images::getAllInGallery($galleryId, $fetchStyle)
Images::updateDescription($imageId, $description)
Images::updateGallery($imageId, $galleryId, $orderNum)
Images::getSingle($imageId)
Images::getFilename($imageId)
Images::getImageIdByFilename($filename)


Galleries::getNameById($galleryId)
Galleries::getAll()
Galleries::getMaxImages($galleryId)
Galleries::checkIfExists($galleryId)
Galleries::createNew($galleryName)
Galleries::getById($galleryId)
Galleries::delete($galleryId)
```

Well, you get the idea. I have been adding these methods as the need for them arises, and in development, I start by just using the `DB` class:

```
//Execute a query
DB::query($query);

//Get a single row
$row = DB::getSingleRow($query);

//Get multiple rows
$rows = DB::getMultipleRows($query);
```

So, I test queries with my DB class, then when they are working, I wrap them in a method of the class that is related to it (Image class for images table, Galleries class for galleries table, etc.).

I feel like this will keep growing and growing as I add new features later on (which may be OK, but I'm not certain). Can anybody critique my method and/or provide alternative solutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this actually sounds pretty good. You seem to have a solid abstraction layer between business logic and data access (This is called [Data Mapper pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html)).

The only problem with this getting big is, that you might end up with methods that overlap. You should also try to maintain a standard naming convenction across both classes.

In Images the method is Images::insertNew and in Galleries it is Galleries:createNew.

Do you actually have models? Because what it looks like is that you have a lot of queries to assemble single values, but not whole objects.

Comment: I just use the results from the queries that these abstraction classes retrieve. As I am writing this, I realize that I use models in my non-php projects... I should probably create them in this PHP project, is that what you are saying?

Comment: Actually that would be a way to get rid of most of those queries, since you can have some standard methods (insert, delete, update, findAll, findById, find (using filter options)) to retrieve your model with all the data you want to have.

If you want to get real precise about which data you want to have (no SELECT * FROM) you can additionally specify which columns or create a custom function.

Comment: I see. So, I could continue with my current setup (data abstraction layers w/out models) and just take care in the naming conventions I use for the methods, OR I could build up some model classes and do away with the abstraction layers?

Comment: No, don't throw the abstraction layers over board. But life will be a lot easier.